# Cannot use functions registered with RegisterNatives

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have an application with a native library, I use `env->RegisterNatives()` in `JNI_OnLoad` to register functions dynamically. Android Studio gives me a [tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMFHR.png) "cannot resolve corresponding JNI functions", with a hint to add `extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL ....`

What is wrong with my `RegisterNatives` call?

Native code:

```cpp
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

jint funCall(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i);
jint npfuncall();

static const JNINativeMethod jniNativeMethod[] = {
        {"funCall", "()v",(void*) funCall},
        {"npfuncall","(I)I",(void*)npfuncall}
};

static const char CLASS_NAME[] = "com/example/nativecpp/MainActivity";

int JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void * reserved)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI_TAG", "JNI_OnLoad Function Call");
    JNIEnv *jniEnv = nullptr;
    if(vm->GetEnv((void **)jniEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI_TAG", "vm->GetEnv Call");
    jclass javaclass = jniEnv->FindClass(CLASS_NAME);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI_TAG", "jniEnv->FindCalss Call");
    jniEnv->RegisterNatives(javaclass,jniNativeMethod, sizeof (jniNativeMethod) / sizeof (JNINativeMethod));
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI_TAG", "jniEnv->RegisterNatives Call");
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

jint funCall(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "funcall", "function called: %d",i);
    return 0;
}

jint npfuncall()
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "npfuncall", "function called");
    return 0;
}
```

Java code:

```java
 package com.example.nativecpp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.nativecpp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'nativecpp' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("nativecpp");
        System.loadLibrary("dynamic-lib");
    }

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = binding.sampleText;
        tv.setText(stringFromJNI());
        funcall(2);
        npfuncall();
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'nativecpp' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public native String stringFromJNI();
    public native void funcall(int i); // Here i get the tooltip
    public native int npfuncall();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the warning you get from Android Studio is harmless: it cannot detect that your `JNI_Onload` function calls `RegisterNatives`. You can ignore or turn off this warning.

Secondly, you need to get your story straight: types in your Java code must match signatures in `RegisterNatives` as well as your C++ function signatures. Assuming that the types you put in your Java code are correct, the `RegisterNatives` table and function signatures must look like this:

```
void funCall(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i);
jint npfuncall(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);

static const JNINativeMethod jniNativeMethod[] = {
        {"funCall", "(I)V",(void*) funCall},
        {"npfuncall","()I",(void*)npfuncall}
};
```

In the future, always use `javap -s` to retrieve the internal signatures from your compiled code (or library code) and copy-paste it into your C++ code. Code that fails to work because of a mis-matched signature is sadly a FAQ here on StackOverflow.

Third, whenever JNI behaves strangely, make sure you are checking *all errors*. The RegisterNatives call probably signaled a failure to you but you failed to check the return value.